# How to make a widget opacity change gradually?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, widget, gradient, opacity

I don't really know if it's possible but I'd like to make a Widget, like a box with some text on it, to have the opacity going from 100% to 0% across it. Here is an example made on Photoshop :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9C8E.png)

I don't know if it's possible or if there is a package which does that, but it would be really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could use a linear gradient.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-flutter-gradient

Answer (score 0):

```
  decoration:
    BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
      image: new DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        colorFilter: 
          ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), 
          BlendMode.dstATop),
        image: new NetworkImage(
          'http://www.server.com/image.jpg',
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

**ColorFilter.mode check the code above**

Comment: Is it possible to make it on something else than an image ? Like a Text()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Container(
      height: 50,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        gradient: const LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.blueAccent,
            Colors.white,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
            ),
          ),
          overlayColor:
              MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.blue),
        ),
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Hello world',
            style: textStyleButton
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```